# Create a new column based on two others and conditionals

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a two column data frame of the form:

```
    Death       HEALTH
0   other       0.0
1   other       1.0
2   vascular    0.0
3   other       0.0
4   other       0.0
5   vascular    0.0
6   NaN         0.0
7   NaN         0.0
8   NaN         0.0
9   vascular    1.0
```

I would like to create a new column following the steps:

1. wherever appears the value 'other', write a 'No'
2. wherever appears the NaN, leave it as it is
3. wherever appears the value 'vascular' in the first column and 1.0 in the second, write 'Yes'
4. wherever appears the value 'vascular' in the first column and 0.0 in the second, write 'No'

The output should be:

```
    Death       HEAlTH       New
0   other       0.0          No
1   other       1.0          No
2   vascular    0.0          No
3   other       0.0          No
4   other       0.0          No
5   vascular    0.0          No
6   NaN         0.0          NaN
7   NaN         0.0          NaN
8   NaN         0.0          NaN
9   vascular    1.0          Yes
```

Is there a pythonic way to achieve this? I'm all lost between loops and conditionals.

Comment: What is in expected output if change first row from `other` to `another val` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create conditions for `No` and `Yes` and for all another values are created original value in [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['Death'].eq('other') | (df['Death'].eq('vascular') & df['HEALTH'].eq(0))
m2 = (df['Death'].eq('vascular') & df['HEALTH'].eq(1))

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['No','Yes'], default=df['Death'])
```

Another idea is test also missing values and if no match conditions is set original values:

```
m1 = df['Death'].eq('other') | (df['Death'].eq('vascular') & df['HEALTH'].eq(0))
m2 = (df['Death'].eq('vascular') & df['HEALTH'].eq(1))
m3 = df['Death'].isna() 

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['No','Yes', np.nan], default=df['Death'])
```

---

```
print (df)

print (df)
0  another val     0.0  another val
1        other     1.0           No
2     vascular     0.0           No
3        other     0.0           No
4        other     0.0           No
5     vascular     0.0           No
6          NaN     0.0          NaN
7          NaN     0.0          NaN
8          NaN     0.0          NaN
9     vascular     1.0          Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to implement your conditional logic using if/else inside a function, and `apply` this function row-wise to the dataframe.

```
def function(row):
    if row['Death']=='other':
        return 'No'
    if row['Death']=='vascular':
        if row['Health']==1:
            return 'Yes'
        elif row['Health']==0:
            return 'No'
    return np.nan
```

```
# axis = 1 to apply it row-wise
df['New'] = df.apply(function, axis=1)
```

It produces the following output as required:

```
      Death  Health  New
0     other       0   No
1     other       1   No
2  vascular       0   No
3     other       0   No
4     other       0   No
5  vascular       0   No
6       NaN       0  NaN
7       NaN       0  NaN
8       NaN       0  NaN
9  vascular       1  Yes
```